# Calculate the Affine transformation matrix in image Feature based registration

Tags: opencv, image-processing, registration, affinetransform

I have two images, one is the result of applying an affine transform to the other.
I can register them using homography by extracting the points using the ORB_create function in OpenCV.
However, I want to calculate the Affine matrix needed for this transformation.
is there any way of doing it simply by having the two images?

[image: re]

Comment: Did you try opencv's findHomography command?

Comment: @Meisam isn't it different from the affine transform?

Comment: If the transformation is pure affine, then the command gives you that, nothing more (unless it isn't). Other than that you could find the line separating the left and the right lobes in the images and find the rotation angle for that line (which is not always easy) Then find the scale change and compute the T matrix by some calculation. The hard part is finding the symmetry line.

Answer (score 1):

Detect a rotated rectangle and use its corners to get your transformation matrix

Use : [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform)   or [getAffineTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getaffinetransform)

Edit: regarding rotated rectangle detection :

Please check this Opencv tutorial on how to find contours and detect rotated rectangles [Creating Bounding rotated boxes and ellipses for contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html)

Comment: How would one detect a rotated rectangle? On what would one apply functions like getAffineTransfirm? This answer seems to go in the right direction but may need additional details.

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to the threshold , find the external contour and detect the bounding rotated rectangle.